# How to combine time series in R with overlapping dates and eliminate overlapping dates from first time-series

Tags: r

I'm a total beginner in R and I'm using it to scrub time-series data. I am using some packages to do this and I have multiple time series I want to combine or join. They are formatted the same with the same column names etc. However they have overlapping dates. I want to join them into one continuous time series and give preference to the second time-series where dates overlap. In other words, delete the duplicate date rows from series 1. It seems like using a full_join with some condition would make sense but no amount of searching is getting me any closer. All the solutions discussed seem to have some more complex criteria like keeping data from both where they overlap and I don't need to do that. Although there are 24 columns of data I've selected for mean temp for the purpose of example. Keep in mind there are 1000s of rows in these two data sets with close to a decade of overlap. I have seen solutions that keep the number where one data set has an NA. In this case I know I only want to keep data from station ID 27950 where there is overlap. I've made a couple overlapping dates in the header for purpose of illustration.

```
station_name station_id date       mean_temp
  <chr>             <dbl> <date>         <dbl>
1 CARMACKS           1527 1999-09-01        -1
2 CARMACKS           1527 1999-09-02        -2
3 CARMACKS           1527 1999-09-03        -2
4 CARMACKS           1527 1999-09-04        -3
5 CARMACKS           1527 1999-09-05        -4
6 CARMACKS           1527 1999-09-06        NA

station_name station_id date       mean_temp
  <chr>             <dbl> <date>         <dbl>
1 CARMACKS CS       27950 1999-09-04        -3.4
2 CARMACKS CS       27950 1999-09-05        -4.1
3 CARMACKS CS       27950 1999-09-06        -6
4 CARMACKS CS       27950 1999-09-07        -2.1
5 CARMACKS CS       27950 1999-09-08        -2.2
6 CARMACKS CS       27950 1999-09-09        -2.3
```

The outcome should be:

```
station_name station_id date       mean_temp
  <chr>             <dbl> <date>         <dbl>
1 CARMACKS           1527 1999-09-01        -1
2 CARMACKS           1527 1999-09-02        -2
3 CARMACKS           1527 1999-09-03        -2
4 CARMACKS CS       27950 1999-09-04        -3.4
5 CARMACKS CS       27950 1999-09-05        -4.1
6 CARMACKS CS       27950 1999-09-06        -6
7 CARMACKS CS       27950 1999-09-07        -2.1
8 CARMACKS CS       27950 1999-09-08        -2.2
9 CARMACKS CS       27950 1999-09-09        -2.3
```

Comment: My first approach would be `library(dplyr); data %>% group_by(year,month,day) %>% %>% slice(n())`, which will take the last-appearing row for each date.

Comment: Just drop rows with duplicates in the `date`-column. However, your sample data does not contain any duplicates.. Please make your sample data reproduce your problem...

Comment: Okay, I've created some sample data that will hopefully clarify things and tried to elaborate. I have a feeling this is a painfully simple task I just don't really know what I'm doing.